# Highstock - Group X axis plugin BlackLabel not working on highstocks library (highcharts)

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to use the highstock library for both highstock and highcharts but I also trying to group X axis categories together using the plugin in the below example from the Highcharts forum: https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=36391

Below JSFiddle is using highcharts library and works fine:
http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/TFhd7/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=TFhd7

Below not working using highstock library:
http://jsfiddle.net/ytLwfsub/

The below are the scripts I am using on my webpage:

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/highchart_groupedaxis.js"></script>
```

The grouped X axis doesn't seem to work with highstock which is what I need for other charts on the application. How can I workaround this and group x-axis together?

Comment: Hi @roa765, This plugin also works for Highstock: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/L9fdvj3x/ but the problem occurs with the newest Highcharts version: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/dzapscgh/ Please report this problem here: https://github.com/blacklabel/grouped_categories/issues

Comment: Raised bug: github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/15647

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the resource: https://code.highcharts.com/js/highcharts.js to your jsfiddle.

I've checked the console<sup>1</sup> and it says:

```
VM41 grouped-categories.js:6 Uncaught ReferenceError: Highcharts is    
not defined    
   at VM41 grouped-categories.js:6    
   at VM41 grouped-categories.js:8
```

By this message, I just take the linked resource and add it in the jsfiddle and it works.

Note also the order of the resources loaded - I can't say for certain, but, I should leave higcharts.js as one of the first resources to load - you can change the order of the added resources by holding the link in jsfiddle and drop it above or under the other already added resources.

Also, I think it depends of the jQuery loaded in the jsfiddle sample, so it might influence somehow in the changes made by the highcharts API.

Here's the [modified jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MauricioSO2021/fc0pznvk/).

---

<sup>1</sup> The error in the console of the browser - not the jsfiddle console. This message keeps showing - even in the working jsfiddle. it *might* be a bug.

---

**EDIT:** This is the [bug posted in the highcharts API website](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/15647) by the OP.

Comment: The error states the following - which is why I thought I only needed Highstock:

Highcharts already defined in the page
This error happens if the Highcharts namespace already exists when loading Highcharts or Highstock.

This is caused by including Highcharts or Highstock more than once.

Keep in mind that the Highcharts.Chart constructor and all features of Highcharts are included in Highstock, so if using the Chart and StockChart constructors in combination, only the highstock.js file is required.

Looks like a bug

Comment: Raised bug to highcharts: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/15647